# Matching Links [Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium

Hello I am having a few issues trying to find the links for stuff using Selenium with python

```
<a class="name-link" 
href="/shop/accessories/wyqibr8gd/h8vy9fid4">Supreme®/Hanes® Crew Socks (4 
Pack)</a>

<a class="name-link" href="/shop/accessories/wyqibr8gd/h8vy9fid4">Black</a>
```

What I am trying to do is get the link for the top product and skim through and match it with the color link which is black

I'm currently lost and all of my ideas aren't working out. If you have any ideas please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is Java but the logic can be reused -

```
//Get the list of all the links
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));

//Get the href from the first link
String hrefFirstLink = allLinks.get(0).getAttribute("href");

//Search all the links for find the href again
for(int i=1; i<allLinks.size(); i++) { //loop from 1 as index 0 has the same link
  if(allLinks.get(i).getAttribute("href").equals(hrefFirstLink)) {
    String color = allLinks.get(i).getAttribute("text");
    System.out.println(color); // this would print Black
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Logic In python**

```
 records = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a')

  for record in records:
     print record.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find all of the links with the associated class "name-link" (the other answers would pull ALL links), then build a map of the WebElements associated with each link.  Here's some (ugly) code that could accomplish that, generating a dictionary where the key is a normalized version of the url that's common between the product name and color, and the value is a list of the links that have that common url:

```
    name_link_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.name-link')

    product_links = {}
    for link_element in name_link_elements:
        href = link_element.get_attribute('href')
        key = urlparse.urlparse(href).path.replace("/", "_")
        if key not in product_links.keys():
            product_links[key] = {}
        if 'products' not in product_links[key].keys():
            product_links[key]['products'] = []
        product_links[key]['href'] = href
        product_links[key]['products'].append(link_element)

    print product_links
```